# Free GUI theme files for Android?

Tags: android, themes, look-and-feel

I want to use a consistent looking, minimalist theme for my Android apps that will look the same for Android 2.2 and above. I'd love to use Halo but it's not available on all devices. I'm not sure what Google expects developers to do here as the default GUI theme on earlier Android versions is pretty terrible.

I've seen some projects that try to let you use Halo on earlier devices but you need to copy an 8mb jar into your project which isn't ideal.

Are there any existing themes I can download and use for free?

I was surprised I couldn't find any websites that offer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll Down a bit here:

http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools/

There are a bunch of GUI kits.

Comment: Can you like to something specific from this? I'm looking for a theme package so that I make an activity use that theme and transform the way the GUI looks (e.g. like the Halo theme packaged with Android). From what I can see, these are collections of icons and .PSD renderings of GUI elements.

Comment: I think you have to use the images to define a custom style.

Comment: I'm looking for something prepackaged. Defining a custom style that looks good is a huge amount of work.